# How does AWS RDS MYSQL SSL work?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, rds

so I setup an SSL connection for my RDS MySQL instance in accordance with these instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport. It seems to work, but I am confused as to how it makes it any more secure. Those instructions offer a single public key that can be used to create an SSL connection for all RDS instances. Unless I am missing something, there is no unique aspect of the key. Maybe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of SSL, but I can't wrap my head around how having a single public key for all RDS instances is secure. Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What instructions?

Comment: whoops, sorry. @jNevill http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_MySQL.html#MySQL.Concepts.SSLSupport

Comment: Checkout this : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography
and this : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Answer (score 4):

The SSL is only for encrypting the traffic between the client and the server (db in this case), its not the authentication used to connect to the database, you still need to provide a user and pass. The reason you can distribute a public key to multiple users is because the nature of it dictates that it cannot be decrypted by anything but the private key. If you think  about it, this is exactly how a secure connection to an https site works, the connection to the amazon db is working the same way.